# Request for Permission Error When Trying to Open SQL Connection

Tags: c#, sql-server-2012, sql-server-data-tools

I have a Visual Studio 2012 SQL Server Database Project, targeting SQL Server 2012, that has one Stored Procedure added. I can debug and publish the project. The SP works, in that I can pass in a value, modify it in code and then return the modified value. The problem that I am experiencing is when I try to open a connection (SqlConnection.Open) to a different database on a separate SQL instance I get the following error.

"Request for the permission of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlClientPermission, System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed"

The same code that is throwing this error works fine in a Console Application.

I am new to SQL Server DB Projects and would appreciate any help. I have searched for a solution, but I have been able to find anything relevant. BTW, this is my first time posting

**This throws error:**

```
public partial class StoredProcedures
{

   [Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlProcedure]
   public static SqlInt32 SqlStoredProcedure3 (SqlInt32 inInt, out SqlInt32 outInt)
   {
       SqlConnectionStringBuilder connBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
       connBuilder.DataSource = "mySqlInstance";
       connBuilder.InitialCatalog = "myDbName";
       connBuilder.IntegratedSecurity = false;
       connBuilder.UserID = "myUserName";
       connBuilder.Password = "myPW";
       SqlConnection sqlCn = new SqlConnection(connBuilder.ConnectionString);
       sqlCn.Open();
   }
}
```

**This works:**

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SqlConnectionStringBuilder connBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
        connBuilder.DataSource = "mySqlInstance";
        connBuilder.InitialCatalog = "myDbName";
        connBuilder.IntegratedSecurity = false;
        connBuilder.UserID = "myUserName";
        connBuilder.Password = "myPW";
        SqlConnection sqlCn = new SqlConnection(connBuilder.ConnectionString);
        sqlCn.Open();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The version of SSDT in Visual Studio 2012 is very old - download the latest SSDT, if you do not have the visual studio 2015 then it will download the shell which is still better than the 2012 version.

The current version of SSDT works with SQL 2012 (2005 upwards) so there is no reason to stick on an old version.